Unique locations and bindings in OpenGL
I have been playing out with OpenGL and am a little bit confused about bindings and locations and their indexing.
My thinking is that locations are mostly used for primitives, that can be easily passed around, while bindings are used for more complex structures. Therefore we use locations for in and out data between shader stages (think vertex -> fragment shader) together with primitive uniforms. On the other hand bindings are used for UBOs and textures.
Now comes the weird part, locations are unique for in data, out data and uniforms, this means, whenever I want to specify in data, I can start indexing from 0, I can do the same with out data, this so far makes sense. However I can also start uniforms from 0, which is a little bit awkward to me.
The same stuff happens with bindings. UBOs start their bindings from 0, the same for textures, again, this is reasonable. Then when it comes to dynamic storage, I can once again start counting from 0 and I haven't overwritten anything.
My main question is, what all types of different and unique bindings and locations exist? This is probably tied to GPU hardware?
So far I have found these categories:
Locations:

In data
Out data
Primitive uniforms

Bindings:

UBOs
Textures (samplers)
Dynamic storage

This is the layout for my vertex shader, most of the stuff I've figured out by trying out stuff together with using RenderDoc.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texture_coordinate;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 fs_position;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 fs_normal;
layout(location = 2) out vec2 fs_texture_coordinate;

layout(location = 0) uniform bool use_texture;

layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform Camera {
  mat4 projection;
  mat4 view;
  vec3 position;
} camera;

layout(binding = 1, std140) uniform Object {
  mat4 model_matrix;
  vec4 ambient_color;
  vec4 diffuse_color;
  vec4 specular_color;
} object;

struct Light {
  vec4 position;
  vec4 ambient_color;
  vec4 diffuse_color;
  vec4 specular_color;
};

layout(binding = 0, std430) buffer Lights {
  Light lights[];
};

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D albedo_texture;

RenderDoc showcasing various slots, which is how I figured most of the stuff out.
If I understood all of this correctly, I can think of bindings as pointers to locations, but still, every piece of data needs to have it's location, either explicit or auto assigned.
The Khronos documentation lists all the various unique groups (locations and bindings, for each enum I can start indexing from 0). So in my example use_texture uniform is of type GL_UNIFORM, camera and object are GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, lights are GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, which explains, why I can always start indexing from 0. Is my understanding correct? What would the type of textures/samplers be?

@CloseVoter: Which information are you missing?

Locations and bindings are not the same thing. A location specifies which "index" a shader element has inside the shader. A binding specifies which OpenGL object is connected to the element. Bindings are only supported for buffer backed objects (UBO, SSBO, textures, ...), but those still have a location.
Take for example a sampler uniform. You can either use it's location and set the texture from the application code, or you can use a binding and set it in the shader directly.
Example with locations:
//Shader
layout(location = 1) uniform sampler2D albedo_texture;

//Client code
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(myTexture);
glUniform1i(1, 2); //Bind sampler at location 1 to texture unit 2

Example with bindings
//Shader
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D albedo_texture;

//Client code
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(myTexture);
//glUniform1i is not needed because the sampler is attached to texture unit 2 in the layout qualifier

Unique Locations
A location has to be unique inside it's group of elements. For each shader object, the inputs and the outputs have it's one set of unique numbers. Uniforms have to have unique locations for the whole shader program.
Note, that items where no explicit location is assigned (like the samplers and SSBO interface blocks in the question) get a unique id assigned during shader compilation/linking.
Bindings never have to be unique. If you want two samplers to read from the same texture unit, then this is perfectly fine. The only requirement is that the bindings match the data that is bound on the client side.

Thank you for the answer, the example with samplers is really helpful, it explains really well the difference between a binding and a location. I have edited the original question, as I'm also trying to understand all the different groups as they not share indexing.
